# Requiring that an object's values have a certain type without index signature

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to require that an object's values all have a certain type without requiring an index signature? Something along the lines of: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20I%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20Y%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20y%3A%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%2099%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20pass%20y%20here%0Afunction%20myFunction(i%3A%20I)%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(const%20key%20of%20Object.keys(i))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20something%20that%20applies%20to%20both%20strings%20and%20numbers%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20fails%20to%20compile%20as%20y%20has%20no%20index%20signature%0AmyFunction(y%20as%20I)%3B).

```
type I = {
    [key: string]: string | number;
};

interface Y {
    a: number;
}

const y: Y = {
    a: 99
}

// pass y here
function myFunction(i: I) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(i)) {
    // something that applies to both strings and numbers
  }
}

// fails to compile as y has no index signature
myFunction(y as I);
```

I would prefer to avoid using `any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a mapped type to force the parameter to only have properties of type `number|string`:

```
function myFunction<T>(i: T & Record<keyof T, number | string>) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(i)) {

    }
}

myFunction({
    a: 99,
    b: new Date()
}); // Error as expected

interface Y { a: number; b: number }
declare let y: Y;
myFunction(y); // OK

interface X { a: Date; b: number }
declare let x: X;
myFunction(x); // Error as expected
```